# Sorting an object java based on string member

Tags: java, sorting

I have an object of a custom type called `Suffix` which is defined as

```
class Suffix
{
      int index;
      String suff;
}
```

I create an Array of objects of type suffix

```
Suffix s[] = new Suffix[10];
```

I need to sort it according to the string `suff` data member. How can I do that? I am unable to understand most of the custom implementations available online.

> eg : 
>   If I have s[0].suff = "hats",s[1].suff = "ats", s[2].suff ="ts". Now I need to sort this array based on the suffix. `("ats",1) , ("hats",0) and ("ts",2)` should be sorted order.

Comment: `I need to sort it according to the string suff data member.`  ?? Example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Arrays.sort(..) if your object extends Comparable interface.

```
class Suffix implements Comparable<Suffix>
{
   int index;
   String suff;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Suffix o) {

     return this.suff.compareTo(o.suff);
  }
}
```

You can use as below now

```
Suffix s[] = new Suffix[10];
Arrays.sort(s);
```

Comment: `implements Comparable<Suffix>` should be safer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You got three possibilities:

1. Write your own sorting algorithm and compare the `suff` String there.
2. Implements the `Comparable<>` interface in your `Suffix` class, Override the `comparteTo()` method and use `Arrays.sort();` which takes the array of Compareable objects as parameter.
3. Wirte a `Comparator<>` and use the `Arrays.sort()` method which takes the array and the Comparator.

The third way have one advantage. If you want to sort by `index` instead of `suff` param, you can pass another Comparator to the `sort()` method.

```
        Suffix s[] = new Suffix[10];

        Comparator comp = new Comparator<Suffix>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(Suffix arg0, Suffix arg1)
            {
                return arg0.suff.compareTo(arg1.suff);
            }
        };

        Arrays.sort(s,comp);
```

You have nothing to change in your `Suffix` class. Hint: You can make an extra class with your Comparators as static fields.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using Comparable as @insert-username-here and @vinayknl said, The other one is using Comparator. Inside the method you want to sort add the following:

```
Comparator comparator = new Comparator<Suffix>() {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Suffix s1 = (Suffix) o1;
        Suffix s2 = (Suffix) o2; 
        return s1.getSuff().compareTo(s2.getSuff());
    }
}
Array.sort(s, comparator);
```

Note: don't forget to add getter.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. This interface will allow your classes to be compared according to your own criteria.

Quick google search came up with [this helpful page](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/).